# Java: How do I loop through characters in a string that have a surrogate pair and print them?

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding

I tried this to loop through the characters in my string and print them. All of them are printing fine except the Deseret Long I (). I have no idea if there are other ways to do this so that the  is printed correctly. Here is my code:

```
package javaapplication13;
public class JavaApplication13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hy\u0500";
        System.out.println(s);
        final int length = s.length();
        for (int offset = 0; offset < length;) {
            final int codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);
            System.out.println((char) (codepoint));
            offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this (Netbeans):

```
run:
hyԀ
h
䍡
y
Ѐ
Ԁ
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you try to convert `int` to `char` (4 bytes to 2 bytes). The value in the `codepoint` variable cannot fit in one `char` in case of surrogate pair. Look, it is called **pair**, because it is a pair of chars. I think the simplest way how you can print it is by using `String.Substring()` method. Or you can convert it to array of char's this way: `char[] ch = Character.toChars(codepoint);` and you can convert this array back to string by simple `new String(ch)`.

Comment: `System.out.println(Character.toChars(codepoint));` works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do this:

```
String s = "hy\u0500";
System.out.println(s);
s.codePoints().forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%c", i));
// or:
//s.codePoints().forEach(i -> System.out.print(Character.toChars(i)));
```